# How can I add an attribute in class before response and remove it after response?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

Hi guys I have an html in which a certain class is added. I want to add a certain attribute in it before the response from API and I want to remove it after the response.

Here is my html

```
<div class="artist-job-search-foo artist-filter" ng-click="$ctrl.changeTypeOfFilter({params: $index + 1, paramsTwo : 'true'});$ctrl.selectedTab = $index" role="button">Audition</div>
```

This is my API call

```
 $scope.callFunction = function(){
    // add attribute in class artist-filter 
    //api call response 
    // remove attribute in class artist-fulter

}
```

Comment: you want to add and remove value in class attribute ?

Comment: Yes man before the response and after the response. Like this

artist-filter{ pointer-events : none  }  and after response remove it

Comment: Would use `setTimeout(function(){ //change class }, 1);` then run your request and in the success, finish with changing the class back.

Comment: please post it as an answer i am new to angular

Comment: Your other option is to build it into your `.ajax()` `beforeSend` callback. @UsmanIqbal I would be glad to if you could provide more complete example of code.

Comment: I did something like this and Thank God it worked                 angular.element(".artist-job-search-foo ").css({ 'pointer-events': "auto" });

Answer (score 0):

Angular have a huge library you can read it in [angularjs](http://angularjs.org) website.

In your case you have to use `ng-class` which can *set/remove* dynamic class.

**see the example**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.myClass = "artist-filter";

  $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(function(response) {
    $scope.items = response.data
  });

  $scope.callFunction = function(item) {
    item.active = true;
  }

});
```

```css
.deactive {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">


  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'deactive': !item.active}" ng-click="callFunction(item)">
      {{item.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: what if i have the div in the ng-repeat and i want to add this class only on those who are not clicked.

Comment: it's so easy because you have list , answer updated, you can toggle items too.